# Problem with the HTTPS protocol (Delphi XE)

Tags: delphi-xe

Doing so, I should get the public IP:

```
function TForm1.GetPublicIp: String;
begin
  IdHttp1.Request.Host := 'https://www.mio-ip.it';
  Result := IdHttp1.Get('https://www.mio-ip.it');
end;
```

The problem is that even if I fill it out without errors, it raises an error when I press the button:

> IOHandler value is not valid

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting an HTTPS url. In order to use HTTPS (HTTP over SSL/TLS) with `TIdHTTP`, you need to assign a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`. Also see [New HTTPS functionality for TIdHTTP](https://www.indyproject.org/2014/12/22/new-https-functionality-for-tidhttp/) on Indy's blog.

Using `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, you will have to deploy the 2 OpenSSL binaries with your app, `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll`. You can get them from Indy's [OpenSSL-Binaries](https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries) GitHub repo. Just note that `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` supports up to OpenSSL 1.0.2u. If you need OpenSSL 1.1.x instead (for TLS 1.3, etc), you can use [this Work-in-Progress `SSLIOHandler`](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) instead.

Or, you can use any other SSL/TLS library you want, as long as you can find (or write) an `SSLIOHandler` for it. For example, SecureBlackbox provides an `SSLIOHandler` for its own SSL/TLS engine. And [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/Bi0T1N/Indy/tree/LibTLS_support/) has an `SSLIOHandler` for LibTLS.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use TNetHTTPClient for Delphi XE8 and up